# Ошибка при загрузки файла на ПК в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Это возникает при отправки файла(например .jpg)
Почему-то не распознаёт тип файла

```
   fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Вот весь код из-за чего возникает эта ошибка

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo','document'])
def photo(message):
    print ('message.photo =', message.photo)
    fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id

    print('fileID =', fileID)
    file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
    print('file.file_path =', file_info.file_path)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    with open("photos/image.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

photo = open('photos/image.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, photo)
```

Замечу что при отправке фото(в сжатом формате) всё работает отлично а если отправлю файл то вот та ошибка выдаёт

Если кто-то знает где можно загрузить документ(именно чтобы было в виде файла так-как в формате фото картинка ухудшается)  с бота на пк скиньте ссылку на ресурс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при отправке боту файла `message.content_type = document`, соответственно `message.photo[-1].file_id` будет `None`.

для сохранения `document`:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def get_docs(message):  
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = 'files/received/' + message.document.file_name
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
```

Comment: Дружище огромное при огромное спасибо тебе за ответ. Помог!

Comment: нзч, вы можете сделать в одном `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'document'])` `if\else` для обработки `message.content_type`

Comment: Так и сделал 